How to use OpenAPI generator maven plugin to consume OpenAPI spec to generate APIs & DTOs in Spring Boot?
In a Spring Boot project, when the OpenAPI spec (spec YAML) is provided, use this spec to generate the code for APIs and DTOs rather that building the REST APIs and DTOs at first and then generating spec for them.
Created a sample POC using Spring Boot (a maven project) to consume a sample OpenAPI YAML spec to generate the REST APIs and DTOs.

Can you tell what exactly your question is?

Create a sample openapi.yaml spec and place it in src/main/resources:
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Employee API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /employees:
    post:
      summary: Save Employee
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/EmployeeDto'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Employee saved successfully

components:
  schemas:
    EmployeeDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string

Steps:

Add  openapi-generator-maven-plugin in pom.xml
Add these dependencies for code (APIs & DTOs) generation: swagger-annotations, javax.annotation-api, validation-api, javax.servlet-api
Add this dependency for Swagger UI: springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui
clean build the project: mvn clean install

Dependencies:
<dependencies>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

OpenAPI generator maven plugin:
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <apiPackage>org.openapispec.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>org.openapispec.model</modelPackage>
                            
                            <configOptions>
                                <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <sourceFolder>/src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                                <implFolder>/src/main/java</implFolder>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

inputSpec:

location of your OpenAPI Specification file (YAML or JSON) within your Maven project
supports both YAML and JSON formats for the OpenAPI Specification file

sourceFolder:

where the generated Java files (DTOs, controllers, etc.) will be placed
default: target/generated-sources/openapi

implFolder:

where additional implementation-specific code generated by the OpenAPI Generator will be placed
default: target/generated-sources/openapi

